# JUnit Tesing tutorials for newbies

Tags: android, junit

Can anyone suggest me some link or tutorial from where i can learn how to write test cases for the apps i develop? I have tried those calculator app and its test cases. other than those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place I know of is junit.org.  What could be better?  What didn't you get out of the ones you tried?

Comment: Am just copying the samples frm net and pasting to the apps and running them. i want to run test cases to other apps i developed.. Am new to android and java..